# Why does JSFiddle render my code differently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been working on a piece of code in JSFiddle. The code displays exactly as expected on JSFiddle, but does not display as expected when I use it in my own HTML file.

Discrepancies between the two would usually be very quick and easy to spot, but as far as I can tell the two codes are effectively exactly the same (apart from the added `$(window).load(function(){` required).

The JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kwuo5bra/

```
 $('.expose').ready(function(e){
        $('.expose').css('z-index','99999');
        $('#overlay').fadeIn(300);
    });

    $('#overlay').click(function(e){
        $('#overlay').fadeOut(300, function(){
            $('.expose').css('z-index','1');
        });
    });
```

My implementation:

```
https://serallo.co.uk/highlight.php
```

I'm dreading an incredibly obvious mistake but I simply cannot understand what I am missing.

Answer (score 3):

If you check the console on your website you'll see this:

> The page at 'https://americanfizz.co.uk/dev/highlight.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

The problem is because your URL uses `https://`, yet the CDN you linked to uses `http://`, hence it's blocked and jQuery is not loaded. You need to use a CDN with an SSL URL.

Also note that jQuery 1.5.2 is **very** outdated. You should upgrade to at least 1.12. Here's a CDN link which should work for you:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
```

With this newer version of jQuery `load()` as an event handler is deprecated. You'll need to change your code to `$(window).on('load', fn)` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it would be something like this! That's what a long night running on coffee alone does to you!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Also note that your use of the `ready()` method on the `.expose` element is redundant and can be removed: jsfiddle.net/kwuo5bra/1

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jQuery on your page with `https` like in your site. Also you are using a old version.

Where you have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
```

Replace by this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also, on your code, the expose() is not a good way to init the element. Use `(document).ready` instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.expose').css('z-index','99999');
    $('#overlay').fadeIn(300);

    $('#overlay').click(function(e){
        $('#overlay').fadeOut(300, function(){
            $('.expose').css('z-index','1');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you run the code before elements are ready. Move your JS code before the closing `body` tag.

Comment: And you use `.ready` method in a wrong way on the `.expose` element.

Comment: OP is running his code under `$(window).load()` which is completely valid. The issue is the mismatch in URL protocols, nothing to do with the JS logic

Comment: True, but he is using `ready` on the element itself, instead wrapping the entire code inside document `.ready` state from jQuery and get rid of vanilla js `load` state.

Comment: That's a good point, although it doesn't solve the issue in the question.